# Drag&Drop HTML5 скрыть исходный элемент

Tags: javascript, html5, drag-n-drop

при использовании Drag&Drop HTML5 , при перетаскивании , появляется "дубликат", который двигается. А как при этом скрыть исходный элемент? т.е. чтоб был только "дубликат"

Comment: интересно за что минусовали? за то что не могут дать правильный ответ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var isDrag; // идентификатор Drag&Drop

if (isDrag) {
   //  делаем базовый объект невидимым
   document.getElementById ("original-drag-object").style.display = "none";
} else {
   // делаем его снова видимым при дропе
   document.getElementById ("original-drag-object").style.display = "block";
   // здесь меням offsetTop/offsetLeft у оригинального объекта в соответствии с копией 
   // и производим остальные действия
};
```

Comment: что значит запущен?
    dragStart,    dragEnter,    dragOver,    dragLeave:
какое из этих событий?

Comment: @Вадим dragStart => isDrag=true, dragLeave=>isDrag=false;

Comment: в каком событии проверяем if (isDrag)? Если на событии dragStart то нет ни того ни другого

Comment: вот тут https://www.html5rocks.com/ru/tutorials/dnd/basics/ в коце есть пример - оригинал изменяется, но как посмотреть? по F12 не удалось..

Comment: @Вадим завтра уже напишу

Comment: как долго ждать?